# Getting started with Julia Multiple Dispatch

Tags: julia

Here's what looks to me the simplest imaginable example of multiple dispatch in Julia - it's the entire (8 line) contents of a file called adhoc.jl.

```
f = function(x::String)
    println("Called first version of f")
end
f = function(x::Float64)
    println("Called second version of f")
end
f("x")
f(1.0)
```

and yet when I run that (via `include("Adhoc.jl")`) julia complains:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching 
(::getfield(Main, Symbol("##17#18")))(::String)
```

With screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pqwM.png)

If I change that second instance of `f` to `g` things work, but that's no longer making use of multiple dispatch. How come I can't get to first base with multiple dispatch?

Comment: I suggest you read about [noteworthy differrences from R](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/#Noteworthy-differences-from-R-1) in the docs (although that specific case is not mentioned there).

Comment: Well spotted for guessing that I am an R user (ex-R user before too long I suspect), and I did read the doc you link to a while back. Reading Bogumił Kamiński's excellent response to my question was an "ah ah!, now I get it!" moment for me. I then needed a regular expression to automatically change all of the Julia code I've so far written from syntax `myfunc = function(x,y,z)` to syntax `function myfunc(x,y,z)`

In case anyone else finds themselves in the same predicament, the regex I used was:
`([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_!]*)\s*=\s*function\(`
with replacement string:
`function $1(`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the corrected version:

```
function f(x::String)
    println("Called first version of f")
end
function f(x::Float64)
    println("Called second version of f")
end
f("x")
f(1.0)
```

The problem with your code is that your original code created an anonymous function and assigned it to a variable `f`. And you did it twice, thus `f` pointed only at `function(x::Float64)`.

You can see the problem with your original code by running it in Julia REPL:

```
julia> f = function(x::String)
           println("Called first version of f")
           end
#3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f = function(x::Float64)
           println("Called second version of f")
           end
#5 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> methods(f)
# 1 method for generic function "#5":
[1] (::getfield(Main, Symbol("##5#6")))(x::Float64) in Main at REPL[2]:2
```

and you see that `f` points at an anonymous function which has only one method.

Running my code (you need to restart Julia REPL as `f` variable name will be already taken and it cannot be reassigned):

```
julia> function f(x::String)
           println("Called first version of f")
           end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function f(x::Float64)
           println("Called second version of f")
           end
f (generic function with 2 methods)

julia> f("x")
Called first version of f

julia> f(1.0)
Called second version of f

julia> methods(f)
# 2 methods for generic function "f":
[1] f(x::Float64) in Main at REPL[2]:2
[2] f(x::String) in Main at REPL[1]:2
```

Comment: That is what I call a great answer!