# What is Multiple dispatch and how does one use it in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have seen and heard many times that Julia allows "multiple dispatch", but I am not really sure what that means or looks like. Can anyone provide me an example of what it looks like programmatically and what it enables?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[From the Julia docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/index.html#Methods-1)

> The choice of which method to execute when a function is applied is called dispatch. Julia allows the dispatch process to choose which of a function's methods to call based on the number of arguments given, and on the types of all of the function's arguments. This is different than traditional object-oriented languages, where dispatch occurs based only on the first argument, which often has a special argument syntax, and is sometimes implied rather than explicitly written as an argument. [1](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/index.html#Methods-1) Using all of a function's arguments to choose which method should be invoked, rather than just the first, is known as multiple dispatch. Multiple dispatch is particularly useful for mathematical code, where it makes little sense to artificially deem the operations to "belong" to one argument more than any of the others: does the addition operation in x + y belong to x any more than it does to y? The implementation of a mathematical operator generally depends on the types of all of its arguments. Even beyond mathematical operations, however, multiple dispatch ends up being a powerful and convenient paradigm for structuring and organizing programs.

So in short: other languages rely on the first parameter of a method in order to determine which method should be called whereas in Julia, multiple parameters are taken into account. This enables multiple definitions of similar functions that have the same initial parameter.

A simple example of multiple dispatch in Julia can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224047/getting-started-with-julia-multiple-dispatch).

Comment: I'd also recommend watching this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kc9HwsxE1OY talk starts at 2.25